# Why are so many different properties required to use a CSS3 property across browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, css

Why when I want to use border-radius do i need 3 seperate browsers?

```
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

Why can't they all just understand `border-radius` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS3 spec is still not finalized. Browser vendors usually keep it as `(vendor)-*` until they think the spec is stable enough.

Chrome, for instance, has started migrating to the standard and removed the `-webkit` prefix for various properties.

Answer (score 1):

Because each browser or to be specific their [rendering engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) have different implementations for that.

Here is the breakdown of that:

```
 border-radius: 10px;          /* standard CSS3 */
-moz-border-radius: 10px;     /* For Mozilla */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;  /* For Safari/Chrome */
```

Note that not all CSS3 properties are different across browsers but yes we aspire them all to be same and standard-compliant stuff for us. IE is far from that :(